# TWTRLogInButton doesn't present the OAuth flow

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, oauth

I am making an iOS app using swift which has to connect to twitter and I use the TwitterKit with Fabric to do that.

I did it as it is shown here : https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios/twitter-login

But, when a twitter account isn't defined in my iOS settings, the TWTRLogInButton doesn't present the OAuth flow to sign in.. Or it should : "The SDK first attempts to leverage system Twitter accounts, via Accounts.framework. If that fails, it falls back to presenting an OAuth flow."

Maybe i forgot to do something, but it is not explained in the tutorial, and i have not found any other response.

My code : (the Twitter.sharedInstance().logInWithCompletion is called at the loading of the view, so maybe it not here that it should be but i don't know where to put it)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    logInButton = TWTRLogInButton(logInCompletion:
        { (session, error) in
            if (session != nil) {
                println("signed in as \(session.userName)");
            } else {
                println("error: \(error.localizedDescription)");

            }
            self.refreshInterfaceBasedOnTwitterSignIn()
    })

    Twitter.sharedInstance().logInWithCompletion {
        (session, error) -> Void in
        if (session != nil) {
            println("signed in as \(session.userName)");
        } else {
            println("error: \(error.localizedDescription)");
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Did you find the way to show the OAuth flow? I have exact the same problem - OAuth flow is not shown, I just get the "Not authorized error".

Comment: Hi! No, i only use it with the Twitter account of iOS..

Comment: To use the OAuth flow on twitter app account the "callback URL" field must be set. After I set the callback URL app shows the web UI for login.

Comment: @EvgheniiTodorov I set the callback URL but it is still not working on other devices.

Answer (score 1):

To use the OAuth flow on twitter app account the "callback URL" field must be set.